# Modifying files in Google Cloud Storage from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an application that is hosted through Google App Engine. It is intended to be a file hosting application, where files are uploaded directly to GCS. However, there is some processing that needs to happen with these files, so originally my plan was to download the files, do the modifications, then reupload. Unfortunately, GAE is a read-only file system. What would be the proper way to make file modifications to objects in GCS from GAE? I am unfamiliar with most google cloud services, but I see ones such as `google-cloud-dataproc`, would these be able to do it?

Operations are removing lines from files, and combining files into a single .zip

Comment: You could do it all in memory without a filesystem if you have libraries that can make that possible.  Reading and writing memory is not that much different than working with a file.  And many serverless compute products only have memory-based filesystems anyway.

Comment: @DougStevenson has the best approach, for people coming back - I found a way to do all of what I needed in memory with BytesIO, without having to create temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the file in the tmpfs partition that you have on App Engine mounted in `/tmp`. It's in memory file system and you will use memory to store files. If the files are too large, increase the memory size of your App Engine instance else you will have a out of memory error

If the file is too big, you have to use another product.

Think to clean the files after use to free memory space.